# Google APi + Passport + React : Authentication flow

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js, google-oauth

I'm using passport to authenticate using Google API, I'm sending a token by URL to the client (React app) which saves it in the localStorage.

I want to use that token : With every API call (get, post, put) I want to send that token to the server , but I didn't know how to verify that token on the server side.

Passport Startegy :

```
app.use(passport.initialize()); // Used to initialize passport
app.use(passport.session()); // Used to persist login sessions

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: 'IDxxxxx',
    clientSecret: 'SecreXXX',
    callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/callback'
},
(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {

    // Directory API here

    var userData = {
        name: profile.displayName,
        token: accessToken
       };

    done(null, userData);
```

Authentication :

```
app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['profile'] // Used to specify the required data
}));


// The middleware receives the data from Google and runs the function on Strategy config
app.get('/callback', passport.authenticate('google'), (req, res) => {
    var token = req.user.token;
    res.redirect("http://localhost:8000?token=" + token);
});
```

API in express (which contains CRUD methods) :

```
app.use('/api', movieRouter)
```

In react side : Getting the token

```
  componentWillMount() {
    var query = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search);
    if (query.token) {
      window.localStorage.setItem("jwt", query.token);
      // appel a directory api (avec token) puis sauvergarder dans redux puis redirection vers liste demandes
      this.props.history.push("/");
    }
  }
```

Doing API calls :

```
import axios from 'axios'

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api',
})

export const insertMovie = payload => api.post(`/movie`, payload)
```

I just need to send the token in every call and check it in the server side.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the token in a header most likely, try changing your axios client to something like

```
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api',
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${your_token_here}`
  }
})
```

I'm not 100% sure if this is the correct header form that passport will be expecting, but it's the general idea you need to do.

Comment: And how to verify that token in server side ? The APIs are still open to public calls

Answer (score 0):

If the token is correctly set in the header, session, or cookie by the client as noted by Bill Metcalf, then express is able to authenticate a route/endpoint by adding the passport.authenticate middleware function to the route, like so

```
app.use('/api', passport.authenticate('google', {failureRedirect:'/login'}), movieRouter)
```

Refer to http://www.passportjs.org/docs/google/ for more information

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fcallback&client_id=-XXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/api/movie/5e46bc5b8467a51ae4b90f3a') from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 0):

For every API that you want to verify the token, you can pass a verify token function (which I call 'isCorrectToken') before taking action like this:

```
router.get("/api", isCorrectToken, (req, res) => {
// your api content })
```

And then, this is our isCorrectToken function:

```
const isCorrectToken = (req, res, next) => {
const token = req.headers.authorization;
if(token){
    const onlyToken = token.slice(7, token.length);
    jwt.verify(onlyToken, accessToken, (err, decode) => {
        if(err) return res.status(401).send({ msg: 'Invalid Token' });
        req.user = decode;
        next();
        return;
    });
}
else return res.status(401).send({ msg: 'Token is not supplied'});}
```

The number 7 is the length of 'Bearer ' (from Bill Metcalf's answer above).